# react-native - Android responds to the styles that it should , but IOS don't

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I have build an application on react-native/expo . The behaviour of the app on Android is " pico bello " perfect aligned , but is not the same story on IOS . I must change almost every prop. to have some proper results . So i ask myself am i missing something that should be done ( i mean specific for IOS ) ? And also i noticed when i try to create an IPA file from the command prompt  `expo build:ios`  it asks me for an AppleID profile with a password . When i provide them it says that it cannot get the credential that were needed . So again am i doing something wrong ? Please release me from my "miseria" , because this problems are bugging me off...